# postgres add a constraint not null if value is true in another table

Tags: database, postgresql, back

I would like to know if it's possible to create table with a not null constraint on a column depending of the value of another column in another table.
(In postgres)

exemple:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Ref (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    required BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Value (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    refId INTEGER REFERENCES Ref(id) NOT NULL,
    value TEXT,
);
```

So here I would like to add a constraint NOT NULL to value if required is TRUE.

So I tried to use some check but it seem that it only check column inside the same table :(.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can (a) migrate the `required` column to the `Value` table, or (b) duplicate it in both tables and then automatically duplicate the values by `trigger functions`, or by `rule`, or (c) implement the constraint in `trigger functions` applying to table `Value` while testing the `required` column in table `Ref`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood that when `required` field is equal to true, then we must set NOT NULL to the `Value` table's field, else set to must be NULL.
You can do this using PostgreSQL check constraints. Firstly we must create a function for checking field values.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_required(p_id integer, p_value text)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
$$
declare 
    v_ret bool;
begin
    select required into v_ret from tbl_ref where id = p_id;

    if (v_ret)and(p_value is null) then 
        return false; 
    end if;

    return true; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLpgSQL;
```

Then we can use this function on the create table process:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_val (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    ref_id int4 NOT NULL,
    "value" text NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tbl_val_check CHECK (get_required(ref_id, "value")),
    CONSTRAINT tbl_val_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT tbl_val_fk FOREIGN KEY (ref_id) REFERENCES tbl_ref(id)
);
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! the function get_required() you created was just what I needed :)